# Feedback for The Loop, August 2020: Community-a-thon recap

Tags: discussion, community, company, the-loop

In this month’s “The Loop” blog post, we did a deep dive and [recapped our Community-a-thon event](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/20/the-loop-august-2020-community-a-thon/) from our [Q2 roadmap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348271/51).

I know that the Community has been eager to hear about how the event went. We waited until now to post so that we could finish sifting through the feedback that we received, and so that we could report on trailing 30-day engagement numbers for staff (comparing numbers for before and after the event). Here is a preview of those numbers:

> - The percentage of employees who visited any main site in last 30 days went from 72.76% (before the event) to 86.84% (19.3% increase).
> - The percentage of  employees who had engagement on any main site in last 30 days went from 24.51% (before the event) to 36.40% (48.5% increase).
> - The percentage of employees who commented, posted, reviewed or edited content on any main site in last 30 days went from 12.06% (before the event) to 19.74% (63.6% increase).

Additionally, we had a question on the pre-event and post-event surveys about people's perceptions of the network and community:

- Pre: 5% were negative, 29% were neutral and 66% were positive.
- Post (from those who responded): 3% negative, 10% neutral, and 86% positive.

Please see [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/20/the-loop-august-2020-community-a-thon/) for more information on event stats and details.

And if you want to *hear* even more about what went on during the Community-a-thon, please listen to [Stack Overflow Podcast 263](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/25/podcast-263-community-athon-2020-turning-our-employees-into-stack-users/), which is all about the Community-a-thon, featuring Yaakov Ellis & Stephanie Cantor as guests.

### Competition and Points

I would like to go into more detail here on the points system that we used during the event to add a competitive aspect and make things a little more fun. There are a few types of behaviors that we were trying to motivate/encourage:

1. Consistent participation: there are some rewards that you get by doing something minimal a few times a week, with bonuses if you can do these every work day in a given week
2. Visiting and participating on lots of unique sites
3. Creating good content
4. Reward feedback and chat participation
5. Extra encouragement for new users

Points were calculated through some really long SQL queries (on non-public tables that aggregate site activity network-wide), and were publicized internally a few times per week throughout the contest.

Point rules were as follows:

- Daily Site Activity

  - 1 point for every day with a visit to a content page (not the home page or questions listing page) on SO or any site in the SE Network.
  - 5 point bonus in any week where this is achieved at least five times.
- Daily Site Engagement

  - 2 points for every day with content created on the network. Content: Question, Answer, Comment, Edit (does not include votes).
  - 10 (20 for new account) point bonus in any week where this is achieved at least three times.
- Unique Site Visit and Engagement

  - 1 point for every unique site visited during the contest (max: 25 points).
  - 2 points for every unique site with engagement (question, answer, comment, edit, review, vote) during the contest (max: 50 points).
  - Additional 2 points for every unique meta site with engagement (max: 50 points).
- Votes

  - 1 point for every upvote received on a question or answer posted during the contest (8 points max per day). 1.5 points if account was from a new user to the network (12 points max per day).
- Chat Participation

  - 2 points for every day with at least one chat entry made in any public chat room.
- Feedback / Bug Reports

  - 2 points for each piece of feedback submitted relating to the usability of a feature or piece of UX on the site, or about the event itself (max 5 per week).

Top scoring participants in each category (all users, fresh users, seasoned users, teams) got a special holographic sticker after the event. All other participants got a non-holographic version:

[image: The Community-a-thon logo. A heart shape made of five horizontal bars. Each bar is a different color. The top bar is red, the second is orange with “Stack Exchange” in white text, the third is yellow and wider than the heart with “community-a-thon” in black text, the fourth royal blue with “2020” in white text and the fifth a navy blue for the bottom point of the heart.]

The top scorers exceeded 250 points over the course of the event, with a median score of 31 among all participants. Almost everyone who scored over 70 points ended up with a holographic sticker.

---

Since this was such a success, we plan on making it an annual event. We are happy to answer any questions below related to the event, and are interested in feedback from the Community about the event, points system, and additional ways in which we can encourage more interaction and empathy between Stack Overflow staff and the Community.

Comment: Can you give some insights on how your "employees" are structured? 25% engagement seems incredibly low for a tech company. Does that mean you have a 75%+ non-tech jobs overhead or does it mean not all technical people use Stack Overflow, even if encouraged to do so?

Comment: In the blog post, what is "MSE"? [meta.se]? [maths.se]? ([magento.se]? [monero.se]?) If it means main meta, I'm surprised that's listed as surely lots of employees are posting here as part of their jobs. Anyway, +1 and thanks for the recap - I was waiting for this!

Comment: @nvoigt I can't give a full breakdown by department here, but I will say that a very good portion of the company is involved in Sales and Operations, departments where no engagement on sites is needed. And even in product/dev, where almost all staff have accounts, many are not active or engaging on a regular basis (like everyone else, most of the time when we have a coding question and end up on SO, we find an answer for our question waiting for us). So even though most may visit on a regular basis (the first stats bullet), engagement is significantly lower.

Comment: @Randal'Thor MSE = Meta Stack Exchange. Many folks on the prod/dev side of the company do post here from time to time (some more than others). But that is only a relatively small portion of the overall number of staff (~250) in the company.

Comment: If engagement includes voting, shouldn't your regular visits to SO finding an answer result in regular upvotes to said answers?

Comment: This is positive change, especially the engagement rates for staff members. Can we please have these stats regularly tracked to ensure that this is kept up? If folks believe they are no longer being tracked there's every possibility of a relapse which just wouldn't do.

Answer (score 30):

Numbers are nice, but nothing beats a good selection of examples. I'm particularly interested in

> 3. Creating good content

Would it be possible to showcase some of the highlights, e.g. in the form of another blog post?

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/parenting/query/1283639/posts-by-stack-exchange-staff-network-wide?fromDate=2020-06-16&tillDate=2020-07-13) is a list of 291 posts across the network, during the Community-a-thon, by users with a staff account on Meta Stack Exchange. So this does not include any separate accounts used for the event, which accounts for the difference with the number of posts (428) mentioned in the blog post.

Comment: While I'm certainly curious, I think it would skew the whole experience when some posts are singled out for the audience to see. After all the goal was to experience SE as it is, as if they were normal people using it.

Comment: @nvoigt if the worry is vote skew, the posts could be copied out instead of linked to. Or shared as a screenshot, though that provides its share of issues, including accessibility.

Comment: Well, they would still be found. And the account would then be known to be of an employee, which ruins the next round of "be one of the normals". You know how SE can be, the post would come under close review and everybody and their dog would find something to nitpick or up/downvote.

Comment: Singling posts out for attention isn't that unheard of, there have been a few initiatives to do so in the past. One of the things that I'm much more worried about would be labelling something 'good content' or singling it out for a blog post/tweet/whatever without talking to the local community/site moderators first, and finding out if it's really 'good content' they want to see advertised, if it represents their site.

Comment: We considered giving a list of the top posts by employees (who wanted to share them), but decided against it: very good chance it would lead to either too much positive or negative attention directed to those posts (and not fair to other content which is also very deserving but doesn't get direct links like that).

Comment: I will say that there were over 15 Hot Network Questions from employees during the event, and if an enterprising user were to search for popular questions on the sites highlighted in the blog post, during the dates of the event, you would probably be able to find some by confirmed employees without too much difficulty.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I realized I might have a way of finding most of them. Would it be a problem to post, say, a SEDE query with results?

Comment: @Glorfindel SEDE data is public, so I don't have a problem with your linking from here to a SEDE query. This will of course only show staff who used an account for the event that was registered as a staff account (many users - myself included - used a new account for the event that would not show up there).

Comment: @YaakovEllis ah, true. But the same holds for the 15 HNQs you mentioned.

Comment: FWIW, here's a question posted by Prashanth Chandrasekar that did rather well on the HNQ: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/233023/116908 There were a couple of attempts to close it, but it managed to survive. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Fairly low quality list question IMO. No effort to show any prior research. Not what should be encouraged.

Comment: @PM2Ring I noticed it too but decided not to mention it for exactly the reasons curiousdannii describes. HNQ can greatly skew votes, especially on questions with multiple answers which tend to stay in the list longer.

Comment: True, it is a list question, and was a classic example of the distorting effect of the HNQ. However, I didn't flag or downvote it because I figured that it was good for the CEO to get a taste of the HNQ effect first hand. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring I will note that a scifi mod pointed out at the top of the comment thread on that question that there is precedent for exactly this type of question on scifi.

Comment: @YaakovEllis: It might be useful to go over some of the posts to see what sort of friction there was. For instance, I'm curious what happened with [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/posts/52830/revisions). People struggle with formatting all the time, but it's not usually easy to get on a call with them and find out what  exactly went wrong. Normally you just have to guess.

Comment: Yes, there is precedent for "popular" questions to flout the rules.

Comment: @Glorfindel per my reading of answes scores in that SciFi question it would get to HNQ even if system counted 3-5 top answers instead of current 10 (because two top answers have got more than 2/3 of all answer upvotes). If system had more reasonable cut-off setting, it wouldn't make much difference in this case - probably it would just stick in hot list for few hours less

Answer (score 28):

Someone needs to check their maths:

- 72.8 to 86.8 is indeed a 19% increase
- 11.89 to 24.5 is a **106%** increase (it more than doubled)
- 12.1 to 19.7 is a 63% increase

Comment: Was just about to say this but then found your comment. I guess they don’t want to change the figures either unless they’re planning on doing it later

Comment: The numbers are wrong in any case, but percentages of percentages tend to be confusing even when the math is right (I've gotten dinged for doing this a few times in the past ) - you can usually get some clarity by just subtracting the first % from the 2nd, e.g. "14% more employees visited"

Comment: Yup, thanks, copied the wrong fields from my spreadsheet. Just fixed it here and on the blog post as well.

Comment: @Shog9 that's also super-wrong. That would be "14 percentage points more", not "14 percent more". They are very different.

Comment: aggh, you're right @Orange. Got too hurried with the edit there. In any case, given the size of the company we're probably talking about 30-40 more people visiting *and* engaging here, which is a nice number of people.

Comment: Ok. So I actually just totally copied from the wrong columns in my spreadsheet for my second bullet point. The original % change was correct, the source numbers were the ones that were wrong. I have corrected this in the post above (and includes two-decimals to give more accuracy as well).

Answer (score 24):

I noticed a fair few positively-received questions and answers from the senior leadership team across the network. It was really nice to see them actively participating!

I have a couple of questions, both general and related to the participants' feedback:

1. How many staff members continued to participate after the event concluded?
2. What are some of the most outstanding pain points described by participants?
3. If asked whether the participants enjoyed engaging with the site, how many responded with a "positive" experience?
4. The [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109421/community-a-thon) that was designated to be used for the event was relatively quiet. What barriers for entry were there, beyond the [reputation gate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)? Did participants simply prefer to talk internally among themselves?

Overall, I'm happy to see that this is going to become an annual event, and I would consider any increase in regular engagement with the network among participants a resounding success. I would also consider *lasting* engagement to be an even *bigger* success, though!

Thank you for even considering running a Community-a-thon in the first place. It shows that SE is willing to get their employees involved in the very product they maintain, which has been a problem in the past. Here's hoping for even more engagement next year!

Comment: I was going to ask about the chat room. Ninjaed

Comment: **1. How many staff**: See the stats above - looking at trailing 30 days after the event, we have ~20% of staff posting at least one piece of content (compared to ~12% before the event). These numbers also only capture staff posting on accounts that are registered as staff accounts.

Comment: **2. Some outstanding pain points**: most common one that I saw across a number of users was 'why was my question closed as a duplicate - the duplicate was different than what I asked, but I couldn't do anything about it'. Honorable mention: on-topic guidance as confusing, poor guidance to new users around what to do and when (how to find a potential duplicate, when to accept an answer and when to reply in commentsm, encourage answers instead of comments). But beyond that, we got feedback for all different sections of the app.

Comment: **3. Perception**: We had a question on the pre and post survey about user's perceptions of the network and community (did not have one ask about "how much did you enjoy the event" in that language). Before the event, 5% were negative, 29% were neutral and 66% were positive. After the event, from those who responded, 3% negative, 10% neutral, and 86% positive. (I added this above as well, as I think that it is worth calling attention to).

Comment: **4. Chat** (1/2): This is all just my opinion based on observations, as we didn't get much feedback about chat (which is indicative on its own, as we did publicize the chat room pretty widely internally). I think that the issues that folks faced getting into chat are fairly representative of what any new user will see: when you show up, you see a bunch of people talking about stuff (and they seem to know each other), and it can be unclear how someone should join who is not used to the medium (or feels like they are not part of the clique)…

Comment: **4. Chat** (2/2):  Some folks just want to do Q&A, and it is unclear how chat should or can complement that. Chat discoverability is also kind of poor. And it can just be kind of intimidating to someone new. That said, we did have fabulous feedback about our mentor/mentee pairings, and are going to try to think of ways to potentially make things like this work with chat moving forward as a way to help new users find their way around (kind of like what we did a few years back with mentoring, though we need to find a way to make it more scalable and discoverable).

Answer (score 23):

...Am I the only person here who is seeing this and thinking, "meh"?

To cut to the point, what I'm not really seeing spelled out in this post or in the blog post is:

- What new places people had the most friction (often <s>mis</s>interpreted as hostility by others).  No indication on which sites people felt like were the toughest to work with or integrate into the community.
- What new sites *overall* were selected, and why.  Stack Exchange is a big place now and there's a lot of sites. It's no surprise that the more popular sites would be selected, but to me that's not a really interesting detail; it'd be more cool to find out that people are finding value in the *niche* sites.  It'd be nice to know if the staff members who visited these sites were going to get some lasting value out of them as opposed to doing this on a whim.
- What staff members felt like they contributed, and what they gained from the site.  I don't think I need to elaborate on this one too much, but it boils down to, did you get your question answered, or do you feel satisfied after answering a question?
- Would a staff member *stay* in the community even if they're not obligated to after this exercise?  Why or why not?

Comment: I think the most valuable result is that staff members have experienced what users (new as well as longer standing) experience in their use of the site. And you can only get that experience when you use the site. So the next time they see a complain or a bug report they will remember having experienced something like that. Whether the staff member is keeping coming to the SE sites has little to do with that, but regular repeats (once a year is now predicted) will fix it better into their memories.

Comment: @Willeke:  It sounds like the "experience" you're describing is about the same experience as using the 9 on a microwave.  That is to say, maybe you've done it once or twice, but that doesn't mean you really know how to use a microwave.  I suppose that reinforces my "meh"; if one isn't really getting to know the site or its community, then a passing visit isn't going to really redress that.

Answer (score 14):

> - The percentage of  employees who had engagement on any main site in the last 30 days went from 11.89% to 24.5% (49% increase).
> - The percentage of employees who commented, posted, reviewed or edited any main site in the last 30 days went from 12.1% to 19.7% (64% increase).

(I think there's a preposition missing before "any main site" in that last bullet point.)

**How is "engagement" defined here?** If people can have engagement without commenting, posting, reviewing, or editing, but more than just visiting the site, then what does that engagement consist of? Flagging? Actively reading posts? Clicking vote buttons even if they don't have enough rep? I'm especially confused because in the "before" figures, *less* employees had "engagement" than the other things, but in the "after" figures, *more* employees had "engagement" than commented/posted/reviewed/edited. That must mean it's possible to do some of those things *without* having engagement?

Comment: Engagement by our definition includes voting, in addition to the other content-creation (or modification) activities listed.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Then I'm still confused how the "before" figure for engagement is *less* than that for commenting/posting/reviewing/editing. Is it possible to comment, post, review, or edit *without* having engagement?

Comment: This was my bad - I copied the numbers for engagement from the wrong columns in my spreadsheet. You are totally right in your analysis. The correct numbers are there now: engagement went from  24.51% (before the event) to 36.40% after the event (which is much higher than the engagement-without-votes numbers in the third bullet point). Thanks for digging on this (leading me to revisit my data and see my mess up).

Answer (score 13):

Simply: thanks for pushing this.

It is super simple: the more SE Inc. employees are being active members of SE network communities, the better. Every single time an SE Inc. employee turns to a community, that is good for both sides.

Thing is: there isn't a perfect strategy to get a workforce to do something specific. Sure, you can ask them, you can order them. But obviously: what you want to achieve is real **buy in**. The employees need to come to the point where they think "I actually like what my boss wanted me to do, so **I** will continue doing it, simply because I like doing it".

That *community-a-thon* is one way to get people moving. Sure, it sounds a bit technical, and somehow feels "typical US manager style". But as said: no strategy is perfect. If you do nothing, the community will complain. If you do X, some members will complain, if you do Y, others will complain. It is what it is, isn't it.

But me personally, I am simply glad that you folks decided to do *something*. It was a first step, and it got some positive results. Now keep the momentum, that simple.

The point I disagree with:

> Since this was such a success, we plan on making it an annual event

Definitely a less than optimal approach.

Community participation shouldn't be asked for/rewarded *once* a year.

Simply make "community participation" *one* part of the goals you set for your workforce. Better not some stupid metric based "you need to gain X reputation on Y communities". But I think it would be useful to have some soft goals, and have your team leads/managers talk about that aspect when doing their occasional 1-on-1 meetings with the people reporting to them.

Example: in our org, we do sprint review meetings every two weeks. At one point, we added the idea of spending 5 minutes on "recognition": we simply sit down and think who did something special that helped us, and then think up good ways to say "thank you". You could do something similar: set aside a few minutes in one of your "repeating" meetings and encourage your workforce to speak about their experiences as SE network users there.

Comment: I like your suggestion, as it essentially seeks to normalize not just participation but *talking about* participation, about first-hand experiences & observations. Not as a formal "we did a study" type of thing (those are also useful) but as an integral part of *being*.

Comment: Thanks, you nicely summarized the essence of my idea.

Comment: I would expect the first interview question to be "Do you use SE sites?". Because really, while developers can do their work without using these, a better combo would be if they want to improve what they are already using. This is called *motivation*. So such devs *should* get priority imho. And then such events makes no sense.

Comment: @Sinatr Not everybody is a developer. Plus: sure, stackoverflow is the biggest community. But there are many others, that have nothing to do with IT. You want all employees of SE Inc to be active *customers* aka community members, in as many different communities as possible. Any way to enable that ... is helpful. Thus I consider your "then such events make no sense" ... to not make sense either.

Comment: @GhostCat, it's quite simple: don't hire developers who don't give a shift about SE. I don't mind if they use reddit, facebook or whatever in addition. But they have to be already loyal users of SE before they get their job at SO company. That's a mistake of company to hire random devs and now they have second problem to fix.

Comment: In deed, you are **over** simplifying things. Sure, it would help if developers are active users, and that is something one can make a criteria in the hiring process. The point is to keep that motivation alive. And as I just said: the SE network has many communities that have no relation to IT. Your approach completely ignores that part. "Do better hiring" ... and then assuming "problem solved" is nonsensical. Because personal motivation can change quickly, unless fostered by the company.

Answer (score 9):

It's great that you tried this. I'm most interested in the next steps hinted in the "Feedback" section. That sounds exciting.

Back here in the present, though, I have a question about one of the bullets:

> - Confusing engagement options

Can you provide some examples for this? SE certainly has lots of "engagement options," and I'm curious what your dogfooding has surfaced in ones that are (and are not) confusing.

Comment: Perhaps that "thanks" button that was around for a bit.

Comment: Some examples of this (which in retrospect, is maybe a confusing and less-than-accurate label itself - I think that I will change it to "missed engagement opportunities"): nothing thanking user for their first post and encouraging them to continue; left answer that helped OP (based on comments) but they didn't upvote or accept answer; no notification when post went to HNQ; not doing more to show value to users when they hit-and-run from google search;

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to disagree on a few points, and ask a few other questions

> @nvoigt I can't give a full breakdown by department here, but I will say that a very good portion of the company is involved in Sales and Operations, departments where no engagement on sites is needed.

A good chunk of the products SE has are *intrinsically* (careers, ads) or extrinsically (Teams, SE Enterprise) linked to public Q&A so while not entirely necessary, it seems... useful. Depends on where you are on ops but knowing *what* your co-workers do day to day also seems handy.

> Consistent participation: there are some rewards that you get by doing something minimal a few times a week, with bonuses if you can do these every work day in a given week

Any way to work out what *retention* is like internally and get feedback to why if folks drift off after 6-8 weeks?

Spevacus' answer raises a few [excellent pain points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353273/135565)

> Chat discoverability is also kind of poor. And it can just be kind of intimidating to someone new.

Chat is nearly impossible to find, and that's been one of my pet peeves for a while. Its a bit of a shame really since in many of the communities that spun off from SE, its well loved, and if it had been in active development, its likely it could have benefited, and helped the company benefit from the whole remote work thing.

Chat *ought* to be brought up to speed to the rest of SE (themes and so on), handling some pain points (My kingdom for an API!) and *shudder* maybe have a few features added on.

I'd love to see some thought into integrating it with teams and enterprise to flesh out the non public offering a bit more for companies who don't want *everything* on slack.

> when you show up, you see a bunch of people talking about stuff (and they seem to know each other), and it can be unclear how someone should join who is not used to the medium (or feels like they are not part of the clique)

Which is kinda true of most chat rooms.

> Some folks just want to do Q&A, and it is unclear how chat should or can complement that.

> That said, we did have fabulous feedback about our mentor/mentee pairings, and are going to try to think of ways to potentially make things like this work with chat moving forward as a way to help new users find their way around (kind of like what we did a few years back with mentoring, though we need to find a way to make it more scalable and discoverable).

Well.. that might work, though it will be interesting to balance "mentoring" with "people who want quick answers and don't want to actually ask on the site". Root Access actually has a "soft" no questions rules cause of that (soft since you can totally [nerd snipe](https://xkcd.com/356/) us).

Comment: I must have missed something. Where are those citations from? The first one is from a comment, but what about all the others? (it's really interesting, I would like to read the full thing if possible)

Comment: Some of it is from comments to Spevacus' excellent answer - I probably should link back, and I will in the morning.

Comment: As for chat's discoverability, perhaps whe can stick it in the tons of free real estate available in the side bar (as long as you are not in a/multiple team(s) that is almost completely empty. Would that be an option @YaakovEllis

Comment: I kinda want to post an FR, but I know there's a dupe target. Some thiinking about how I want to approach it is needed ._.

Answer (score -35):

> I know that the Community has been eager to hear about how the event went

Do you mean [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)?

I am not sure why would SE users want to know about some internal event of some company. It should belong to a company blog for investors and job seekers.

How does it affect users and sites? Why was it announced and featured?

Comment: "How does it affects users and site? Why it was announced and featured?" Those answers are in at least the current blog post linked in the question or, if you prefer, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348271/2020-community-a-thon-increasing-se-staff-engagement-with-our-sites-and-communi). Or if you'd like a tl;dr, employees using their creation and understanding how we use it directly benefits us because they control the way the direction of the site.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose, don't get me wrong, but I am not reading SO blog. It's funny that SE users are in fact reading SO blog.

Comment: Uh. You do realize that posting feedback posts on MSE is something folks in the community fought hard for. A lot of things in the blog does affect us and bridging those two fora is one of the ways we expected the company to better engage with us. A lot of the damage over time is because the company lost touch with the community and this is one of many things that might help them reconnect with the network as a whole

Comment: @Sinatr The link I gave was to a MSE post. The blog is, ostensibly, relevant to the entire network despite the name. And on the topic of things we find humorous, people writing answers on posts about blog posts without reading said blog posts is definitely up there for me. ;-)

Comment: You seem to be [contradicting yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347592/369802)... I think you should pick a clearer point to fight for, because saying this belongs on the blog while telling other people to post on the site instead of the blog... simply makes very little sense to me.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell, I don't. First of all I don't mean ALL posts from blog should go here. This so-called *announcement* is not something I personally want to know about. [There](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347592/299295) I was asking for announcements which are important. Secondly if post go here - it should go in FULL. Not just one paragraph and "please read more [blog link]".

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, how would information about company internal events help you to trust company decisions? Intransparency in decision making won't improve if you know who and when go to pee. You need to be aware about important stuff, not just *any* stuff.

Comment: The CEO blog post was for 'community and customers', and both the MSE post and blog mention that a few times. You were arguing it should go onto a place where only the community could find it. Now, there's a thing which was done for the community, and you're arguing that it should be in another place because it's for investors and job seekers... It's contradictory, and it makes little sense. Just because you don't want to read it doesn't mean others don't. Why bother making the fuss? Also, this isn't an 'announcement', it's a post wrapping up the conclusions of an event.

Comment: @Sinatr Many of us think it *is* important. We've told you several reasons why we think that it is and we've pointed to other posts explaining even further. Instead you've deemed this unimportant without actually making any effort to try understand what the event even was or engage with the explanations given to you (as evidenced by your answer and comments), and the community so far seems to disagree with that (as evidenced by the votes).

Comment: agree that statement about community being eager to hear feels a bit like coming out of thin air here. It would look more solid if they referred meta posts indicating why they think so. One example that springs to mind is, [Require Participation in a Community Before Making Decisions that Affect That Community's Future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387435/839601) (there may be more, I didn't seek)

Comment: @gnat, to me this announcement is another marketing move, nothing more and obviously it has nothing to do with community. I am suprised to see many downvotes, perhaps my tone is wrong, but upvotes on the question are very well telling us about how community is interested in knowing such an important information.

Comment: don't let marketing speak trick you. Wording in some parts of this announcement may read like from "progress report to investors" but if you look at the substance, this event doesn't have any marketing impact. Or more precisely, it may lead to some impact - but in the long term and in rather subtle and indirect ways - ie it's not something you'd want to brag about to investors

Comment: ...as for downvotes, my guess is, main point of your post seems to be that this announcement belongs to blog for investors and some folks may find that it's not sufficiently backed up (I also think so, although I didn't vote down because your other points look well taken)

Comment: Considering the utter trash from the blog that used to be pushed across the network, they've shown real restrain in what they're now tagging as an announcement.

Comment: Last year, everybody was complaining that SE Inc workforce wouldnt use the SE network sites. Now they do, and their leadership encourages that ... and what comes back: complaints.

Comment: @curiousdannii The company that used to manage our blog instance a year or two ago *really* liked consultancy and change fees. We only relatively recently figured out that they actually prevented posts from appearing in the main RSS feed if they weren't tagged with "announcement", heh. That's been fixed, and we can now have much saner tagging in place.

Comment: @AdamLear Oh interesting. Well whatever the reason, I'm thankful! By being more restrictive about what is tagged you help ensure we actually see what is important.

Comment: @AdamLear, I don't understand. Are you saying what blog posts go 1-to-1 to MSE? But post looks *tuned* to me (at least this sentence "please see this blog post for more info" should've been added). I am actually quite fine if *all* blog post come here, but if they are cherry-picked, than my complain is still: please don't choose posts which have nothing to do to the SE sites to appears on MSE.

Comment: @Sinatr I was just talking about how blog posts are sync'd to the community bulletin (the yellow box at the top of the right sidebar).

Comment: "[...] want to know about some internal event of some company." It's not some company, it's literally the company which have had a major influence on me over the past years, the company in charge of the beloved community that allowed me to soar to my current programming carreer. I most definitely want to know about this. The engagement of employees with the community have been a major litigious point in the past years. I downvote this answer because it is wrong, not because of the tone or whatever. It's the content that's incorrect.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, it's good to know you want to know. I don't. And while SO matter a lot in my professional life I know nothing about company behind. Nor I want to know. The announcements about SE sites should be posted here instead of blogs. Company events - please keep me *uninformed*, thanks.