# Link to "recent meta posts" search results in "read-only mode" banner contains redundant tags

Tags: bug, notification-bar, maintenance, read-only

The site has this banner right now that there is an ongoing maintenance:

> This site is currently in read-only mode. We’ll return with full functionality soon. Follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus), visit [our status blog](https://www.stackstatus.net/) or search [our recent meta posts on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest) for more info.

I want to ask, why is it that the link for the recent meta posts are for tags [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) and [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) even though they are the same?

---

Edit:
I noticed that the tag names are [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) and [site-maintenance](/questions/tagged/site-maintenance), but it seems as if they are synonyms now. This should probably be fixed later.

Comment: I am not seeing the notice here on MSE. But, yes, tag synonyms. The message in the banner could probably be updated.

Comment: I'm from Math.SE. Can I ask if you could check the site?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it on [Math.SE]. Sorry, I thought by "this site", you meant the site where you posted the question, which is Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to edit that part, but for others who would change the tags if necessary, please edit that part to avoid trivial editing.

Comment: Although it's odd because some sites like Code Review are not read-only. @CodyGray

Comment: @for-the-love-of-soupless That's probably a bug. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377247/348196) for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [math.SE has been stuck in read-only mode for 7 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377254/math-se-has-been-stuck-in-read-only-mode-for-7-hours)

Comment: Why are we voting to close this? That link does indeed search for two instances of the maintenance tag after [tag:site-maintenance] was made a synonym of [tag:maintenance], which could stand to be updated to just search for [tag:maintenance]. This isn't a duplicate of the currently-proposed dupe at all.

Comment: To clear things, I asked about why Math.SE was still read-only at that time as a side question. My main point was the link found when the site was read-only. Additional information for @Spevacus.

Comment: @shadow Can you please explain the reason for your edit? The link was HTTP and didn't include www even during today's maintenance.

Comment: @RandomPerson because it's not relevant to the bug reported here, and just cause people to waste time when clicking it. (It makes the browser load for few minutes before timing out.)

Comment: Acknowledged and likely easy to fix alongside other changes, but in terms of priority IMHO this is way lower than fixing the URL to the status page. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand This [just came up again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398004/why-did-the-recent-maintenance-notices-point-to-a-search-for-maintenance-or-m). I really don't see why simply modifying a URL in a text notice is something that cannot easily be done in a minute - it would be nice if that were explained.

Comment: @Sonic It's not about changing the text. It's getting it deployed. I can't really get into much detail, but I can assure you, it's much more complicated than what you're suggesting.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I guess that makes sense, at least for why this cannot be [tag:status-completed] quickly (deploying during maintenance doesn't make sense). However, it would be nice if the text were still changed in the code, so it'd at least be fixed for *future* site maintenance periods (i.e., [tag:status-planned]).

Comment: @Sonic I'd say the argument is similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396778/site-maintenance-saturday-february-24th-2024-1400-2200-utc-9-am-5-pm?cb=1#comment1327770_396778). The site was read only for _minutes_, and isn't something that happens very often. The level of effort to fix the tag name in that link is a lot higher, even if you don't believe it (and I was skeptical at first too).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Now that I think about it, it doesn't make much sense to keep changing the URL there, especially if the tags are renamed again or de-synonymized - editing it to keep up with community retags (which is what happened here) would be too prohibitive. Still, however, it'd be nice if the other two solutions in the answer to the question I linked above were implemented, since those would remove the requirement to keep editing the notice to keep up with community tag changes.

Comment: @Sonic sure, but the last time we had to make an update to the status page, because of the complexities I alluded to, it took several tries over a couple of months. And we haven’t touched it since. To fix a redundant tag that has no real problem except that it lengthens the url by a handful of characters, I think I’ll have a hard time justifying that effort.

Comment: @sonic I’m not against the other changes you proposed, but then we’re talking a different feature request than “fixing” the status page. Easier to fix the app IMHO, and much more juice for the squeeze (all the time, instead of for a few minutes a quarter, or so).

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find this post because it isn't tagged [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) but it's a good time to bump it.

So the bug in the read-only banner in the notification-bar is still there. If you click the ending link: [our recent meta posts on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest).

[image: the read-only banner]

You are taken to MSE with search containing two repeated tags (the latter having been synonymized to the former) and the `or` search operator i.e. `[maintenance] or [maintenance]`:

[image: MSE main page search]

There's no need to keep the second tag lengthening the URL and have a pair of repeated tags in the search box.

Comment: This is still happening, I experience the duplicate maintenance tags https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktSVb.png after clicking the link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest