# What, if any, is the purpose of duplicate [maintenance] tags in the search results linked from the banner indicating the site is in read-only mode?

Tags: bug, tag-search

The page from the link inviting one to search [our recent meta posts on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest) has two [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) tags.

[image]

Is this a bug, or deliberately status-by-design?  If the latter, what is the purpose of searching with double-tags?

Comment: Existing bug report: [Link to "recent meta posts" search results in "read-only mode" banner contains redundant tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377249/335251)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second tag is the now merged synonym [site-maintenance](/questions/tagged/site-maintenance), which redirects to the main tag [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance). It should just be dropped from the URL/search entirely.