# Chat is hungry in read only mode and keeps quietly snacking on my posts

Tags: bug, chat, maintenance, read-only

During today's [maintenance period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382050/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-wednesday-21-september-0030-0300-utc-tues):

[image: animation showing message posted to chat and gone]

I noticed that there wasn't any indication on chat that it was down, and messages would attempt to get posted, just to vanish into thin air, which seems ... rather unusual behaviour.

I do realize there was a great big banner on the main sites - but I wasn't really paying attention. Could we (in the future) consider ways to let people know in chat that chat is in read only mode or down, and have a slightly... more obvious failure mode?

Comment: This is still happening for me on chat.SE, even though chat.SO is working and main/meta sites appear to be operating normally.

Comment: Strange. Chat.SE seems ok to me - as is chat.mse

Comment: Interesting. It required a Ctrl-F5 reload, not just an F5. It's working for me now too. Nope. It appears it was a timing of attempt issue, as other tabs for other rooms, which have not reloaded, appear to be working fine.

Comment: Just acknowledging this is on our list of items to investigate today; it is certainly not expected that the chat interface should even think about allowing you to post while the entire network is read only.

Comment: @AaronBertrand mind tagging it [status-review] in that case?

Comment: @Luuklag I need to understand what the expected behavior is, part of this may be totally normal, please give us some time.