# Some Users have an AccountId being Zero

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts, network-profile

We know account creation is finicky from answers to questions like [Why is my profile messed up on a single site and how can I revert it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281790) among [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae).

In some of these cases you end-up with a user-profile but no network account. In technical terms: The accountid for that User in the Users table is null.

Somehow 4 "users"(?) managed to create user profiles on two different sites with the accountid being 0. So that is not null, but it is not working either. These users do have a network profile button, but clicking it brings you to the panda.

Here is the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/photo/query/1793924):

```
select 'photo.se' site
     , id
     , accountid
     , displayname
     , concat('https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/', id, '|',displayname) [link]
from [StackExchange.Photography].dbo.Users
where accountid = 0
union all
select 'math.se'
     , id
     , accountid
     , displayname
     , concat('https://math.stackexchange.com/users/', id, '|',displayname)
from [StackExchange.math].dbo.Users
where accountid = 0
```

I have two questions:

- Can / Should these accounts be fixed?
- Is having no network account / aka no accountid in the Users table a valid case?

Comment: I say safe to nuke all four, no activity whatsoever.

Comment: Looks like all of them were created on 2022-09-21 (00:36-01:53)? I wonder if something happened on that period...

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Hmm, I didn't look that far. Maybe a rogue build that got reversed.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. or database hiccups, causing some of the queries to fail without crashing the whole code, so the code thought it was successful while it wasn't.

Comment: Looks like this is the cause: [Planned maintenance scheduled for Wednesday, 21 September, 00:30-03:00 UTC (Tuesday, September 20th, 8:30-11:00 PM EDT)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382050/241919)

Comment: [Some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383644/how-to-reset-or-remove-words-from-exclusion-list-un-ignore-them-in-spell-check#comment136245718_76383644) have the exact same timestamp as the question (probably unrelated).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum probably the OP did post the answer at the same time, by ticking the "*Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style*" checkbox on the Ask Question page.