# Make saves listing visually indicate deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, design, deleted-answers, saves

In the current Saves List UI, deleted answers are shown the same as non-deleted answers. If an answer is deleted along with its parent question, then the question and the answer are highlighted in red in the listing. I would like it to be such that if the answer is deleted, but the question is not deleted, just the part that shows the answer post summary be highlighted in red.

Comment: In other words, the red highlight is based on whether the parent question is deleted rather than if the answer is deleted.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog well, it's technically correct, since the answer must be deleted if the question is (afaik). But it's incomplete, which is the point of this FR

Comment: I wonder if it used to be like that when it was Favorites/Bookmarks? If so, this can be considered a bug.

Comment: @starball Just FYI: It is *possible* for an answer to not be deleted when the question is deleted, although answers are always supposed to be deleted when the question is deleted. Such non-deleted state is typically the result of some sort of moderator action causing the answer to be undeleted (e.g., an actual undelete vote or disputing red flags, which has the side effect of undeleting and unlocking the post). However, I vaguely recall seeing some non-deleted answers to deleted questions for which the cause of the answer not being deleted was unclear (IIRC, there's a meta post somewhere).

Comment: @Makyen probably some temporary database outage, causing odd things all around. See for example [rene's recent question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394291/some-users-have-an-accountid-being-zero), asking about users with network account id of 0.

Comment: A similar thing is happening in the [list of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394032/323179).

Answer (score 2):

I found your question when I was checking for duplicates when I wanted to report this as a support question (or bug) under the title:

**Why are "saved" deleted answers not highlighted in red or pink when viewed in a saves list?**

Here are two answers saved in one of my saved lists:

[image: two answers saved in a saved list, one answer was deleted]

However, the second answer was deleted as can be seen here in "deleted answers":

[image: second answer as it appears in "deleted answers"]

To reproduce this all we need to do is go to "deleted answers" and save an answer to a Save list and then go view that Save list.

This very much looks like a bug rather than a feature request because a deleted question is clearly highlighted in red or pink when viewed in a Save list.

I guess you would like to see the following instead:

[image: mock up of a highlighted deleted answer in a Save list]