# math.SE has been stuck in read-only mode for 7 hours

Tags: support, status-completed, math-se, read-only

Since [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377247/172855) doesn’t seem to be drawing any attention from anyone who can do something about it, I’m posting it as a question. The Mathematics Stack Exchange has been in read-only mode for 7 hours now; it seems that the other Stack Exchange sites are back to normal, so perhaps Mathematics was somehow forgotten in the process of switching back?

Comment: I've now been automatically logged out and can't log back in – "Login is currently unavailable".

Comment: Well it's in the ticketing system and it's a few hours to dawn in New York. Best I can do on my end ._.

Comment: Great ! Only one site still down, and this must be the site I almost only used since a year. Typical for my bad luck !

Comment: Sorry for this oversight, we’re on it.

Comment: Things are back to normal at MSE, thank you @AaronBertrand.

Comment: The site is back. We'll post an answer when we have a full explanation of what happened.

Comment: [Mathematics is restored](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1504787196829708295?cxt=HHwWjsC5mfP-ieIpAAAA)

Comment: [status-unstuck]

Answer (score 18):

*{ cross-posted from [Why is MSE still down (read-only)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34652/13515) }*

### What happened?

During our [planned maintenance window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376901/165455) on March 17th/18th, a sequence of events in our Colorado data center left [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) in read-only mode for several hours after the maintenance was finished.

### TL;DR

**The site is back up**. The maintenance window was officially closed on March 18th at 01:28 UTC, at which point all other sites were fully operational, but Mathematics remained in read-only mode until it was manually corrected at roughly 11:46 UTC.

### What caused the issue?

A number of factors contributed to the issue itself and our failure to recognize it. The long version:

- As part of our manual failover process, we move all sites to read-only mode due to a [performance issue we’ve been experiencing for months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367631/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-thursday-july-29-at-1200am-utc-wednesday-ju#comment1225025_367631) but have yet to solve.
- This involves shifting site traffic to our web servers in Colorado, where they can read data from the secondaries there without any impact from operations happening in New York.
- Fundamentally, the application should not try to write to a read-only secondary; if successive attempts fail, the source site is automatically switched to read-only mode for safety, because it’s a clear sign that something is awry.
- In this case, the Mathematics site did try to write to a read-only secondary following a very specific (non-nefarious) sequence of events from an end user.
- Because this happened while all of the other sites were in read-only mode, any notifications about this site specifically were silenced for maintenance, as we were intentionally setting the entire network read-only and also doing maintenance that would cause significant alert noise anyway.

### What contributed to the duration?

At the end of our maintenance window, we spot check a handful of things, including a few specific web sites (but certainly not all of them). We don’t manually open every single web site in a browser to ensure the banner is gone, or test that we can successfully post a comment or vote on a post.

In this case, all of the places we checked at 01:30 UTC looked good, including our open-source monitoring tool, [OpServer](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver) - which provides a fantastic pulse on the state of our databases. If a specific site’s primary database couldn’t be written to, we certainly would have seen it there. But the site itself does not surface its status there - that is shown elsewhere, on an internal dashboard. So we went to bed.

### How can we improve?

We can improve internal notifications and time to resolution for this scenario:

- We can manually detect when a site is automatically shifted to read-only in response to a scenario like the above ***{done}***
- We can automate and alert on that monitor
- We can further improve the way the application attempts to write to the database during maintenance
- We can add to our maintenance window runbooks:

  - Checking the internal dashboard in addition to OpServer and other checks ***{done}***
  - Increasing the number of sites we spot check
  - Waiting an hour and checking meta (though there are a lot of individual meta sites to check, too)

Comment: Regarding *Waiting an hour and checking meta (though there are a lot of individual meta sites to check, too)* - that's certainly doable. When I had the time for it, I had all meta sites' websockets for new questions linked to [a notification system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318926/295232) and the influx of new questions was (usually) manageable. A cross-site SEDE query (run directly on the real meta DBs, of course) would work too, and I know you're capable of writing one :)

Comment: @Glorfindel That's probably fair, but that's kind of like a last-resort catch-all. I'd much rather know about an issue before any user does. :-) (Also, some of the first bits of meta activity were comments on the original maintenance notification and not new posts.)