# Planned Maintenance scheduled March 2nd, 2023 at 01:00 AM UTC (March 1st, 2023 at 08:00 PM EST)

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

**MAINTENANCE NOTIFICATION**:

Sites may be in read-only mode on [Wednesday, March 1st 8:00 PM EST](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2023&month=3&day=2&hour=01&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=24&p4=179&p5=136&p6=240) / [Thursday, March 2nd 1:00 AM UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2023&month=3&day=2&hour=01&min=0&sec=0&p1=224&p2=75&p3=24&p4=179&p5=136&p6=240) for up to 90 minutes.

**TL;DR**:

The Platform Engineering team at Stack Overflow is planning to perform SQL Server failovers to facilitate required maintenance. We plan to perform this maintenance in a much less disruptive fashion than previous maintenance sessions. However we may require the sites to be in read-only mode for up to 90 minutes.

**The Details**:

We need to perform software patching in order to keep our systems up to date and secure. Some of this work will require our servers to be failed over and rebooted. Since the last maintenance period we have completed work which we believe will enable us to perform these actions in a less obtrusive fashion than in previous maintenance windows. This is the first major maintenance since that work was completed–our plan will be to avoid a network-wide read-only window, but we are including a contingency plan should we encounter unexpected problems to fall back to the previous methodology, which would require the network to be placed into read only mode for up to 90 minutes.

**Questions or concerns?**

Please post a comment or answer below; We'll do our best to address any concerns between now and the maintenance window.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but it would be great if you can have a consistent notice period ;)

Comment: We'd planned to have this up yesterday @RandomPerson but there were some crossed wires in the internal communication. :D

Comment: @RandomPerson Also, they could just do it and _not_ tell us. I think they have SLAs (and "best effort" notifications) around a free, public web site merely as a courtesy. :-)

Comment: It seems that only _some_ sites (e.g., [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/); [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOe18.png)) are read-only while others aren't (e.g., MSE, Stack Overflow, [The Workplace Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/)). Is this a bug? Possibly related to / a regression of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377254/348196)?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine That's just normal behavior for this maintenance window.

Comment: Didn't notice _any_ read-only time over on [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), so that's nice.

Comment: It would be great if you used a proper 24h format.

Comment: As far as I can tell we're not in the maintenance window, but the site seems to be unresponsive.  "*Stack Overflow is currently offline for maintenance*" :-\ This is becoming a common occurrence in the middle of the day.  Quite frustrating!

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue just had it in my GMail yesterday, for 10 minutes. There's not a single site or service in the world with 100% uptime.