# "Asking a good question" starter sentence sounds off

Tags: discussion, meta, asking-questions, wording

This is what the popup says when you attempt to ask your first question here on Meta Stack Exchange:

> ## Asking a good question
>
> This is **NOT** Stack Overflow - [**Ask your question on Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)
>
> [What is meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) It's the site about the sites! (...)

I don't know if it's just me, but doesn't that first sentence about Stack Overflow sound a little off?

This sentence would be fine if I wrote a programming question and the system detected it. But I haven't even started writing my first question and it tells me to "Ask your question on Stack Overflow", giving me a link to do so. That's not what I intend to do or *should* intend to do. I want to ask a question on Meta SE and I should not post it on SO.

I suggest rewording this phrase. What about "If your question is about programming, [ask on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)"?

Comment: "*But I haven't even started writing my first question*" we are constrained by technology - there is currently no mind reading over HTTP. However, what we *do* know is that there are *plenty* of questions asked on Meta.StackExachange which actually belong on Stack Overflow. Some days it's about half the questions posted. Some days, the ratio is not that low.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, the popup appears on the first question you write the moment the page loads (i.e. before you start typing). It should know that this is a user's first question. Apart from that, I'm not going to disagree about how many SO questions are on Meta.SE

Comment: The context there was that you seemed to expect the system to "detect" a programming question. Which it cannot, even if the question was already written. It cannot read your mind. Can't read it before or after writing your question. What we do have is past data of many users posting programming questions.

Comment: @VLAZ The part about "detecting programming questions" was a hypothetical case showing where this message would be relevant. The point of this question is to suggest a change to the message when it is shown before the user starts typing.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand also commented on this in [his observations from the 2022 Community-a-thon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383670/335251).