# Will there be a Community-a-thon 2023, and if so when will it begin?

Tags: discussion, community, company

After reading [Rosie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/943183/rosie)'s post about [sunsetting Winter/Summer Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392846/), I wanted to know if Community-a-thon will continue or not.

Also, are there any pre-defined dates for Community-a-thon?

| Community-a-thon year | Start date |
| --- | --- |
| [2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348271/) | June 16 |
| [2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367628/) | July 20 |
| [2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383022/) | October 19 |

The dates don't seem to have something in common like Winter Bash. So, who decides the dates of the Community-a-thon event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we are doing Community-a-thon this year. It is going to be a scaled-down version and last for a shorter time period this year. [You can read more details about this year's event here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393326/community-a-thon-2023-kicks-off-on-october-13th)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Rosie! BTW, who decides the dates of the Community-a-thon event?